# Training a model with while loop

Tags: python, machine-learning, while-loop, dataset

I am trying to iterate some values while the length of my dataset S_train is <= than some given number, 11 in this case.
This is what I have so far

```
S_new = train
T_new = test
mu_new = mu
mu_test_new = mu_test

while len(S_new) <= 11:
  ground_test =  T_new[target].values.tolist()
  acquisition_function = abs(mu_test - ground_test)
  max_item = np.argmax(acquisition_function) #step 3 : value in test set that maximizes the abs difference of the energy
  alpha_al = test.iloc[[max_item]]  #identify the minimum step in test set
  S_new = S_new.append(alpha_al)
  len(S_new)
  T_new = T_new.drop(test.index[max_item])
  len(T_new)

  gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(
    # kernel is the covariance function of the gaussian process (GP)
    kernel=Normalization( # kernel equals to normalization -> normalizes a kernel using the cosine of angle formula, k_normalized(x,y) = k(x,y)/sqrt(k(x,x)*k(y,y))
        # graphdot.kernel.fix.Normalization(kernel), set kernel as marginalized graph kernel, which is used to calculate the similarity between 2 graphs
        # implement the random walk-based graph similarity kernel as Kashima, H., Tsuda, K., & Inokuchi, A. (2003). Marginalized kernels between labeled graphs. ICML
        Tang2019MolecularKernel()
    ),
    alpha=1e-4, # value added to the diagonal of the kernel matrix during fitting
    optimizer=True, # default optimizer of L-BFGS-B based on scipy.optimize.minimize
    normalize_y=True, # normalize the y values so taht the means and variance is 0 and 1, repsectively. Will be reversed when predicions are returned
    regularization='+', # alpha (1e-4 in this case) is added to the diagonals of the kernal matrix
     )
  
  start_time = time.time()
  gpr.fit(S_new.graphs, S_new[target], repeat=1, verbose=True) # Fitting train set as graphs (independent variable) with train[target] as dependient variable
  end_time = time.time()
  print("the total time consumption is " + str(end_time - start_time) + ".")
 
  gpr.kernel.hyperparameters
  
  rmse_training = []
  rmse_test = []


  mu_new = gpr.predict(S_new.graphs)

  print('Training set')
  print('MAE:', np.mean(np.abs(S_new[target] - mu_new)))
  print('RMSE:', np.std(S_new[target] - mu_new))
  rmse_training.append(np.std(S_new[target] - mu_new)

  mu_test_new = gpr.predict(T_new.graphs)
  print('Training set')
  print('MAE:', np.mean(np.abs(T_new[target] - mu_test_new)))
  print('RMSE:', np.std(T_new[target] - mu_test_new))
  rmse_test.append(np.std(T_new[target] - mu_test_new)
```

Basically, I am calculating the value in T_new that maximizes the abs error between the ith element in T_new and mu_test and adding it to the set S_train, then delete it from T_new.
With the new S_train, I will train my model again, and then do the same I explain above.
I have never used a while loop and I am looking for the sintaxis, for me looks correct, but I get this error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-55-d284ca5f9d1f>", line 42
    mu_test_new = gpr.predict(T_new.graphs)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you know what is what might be causing it? Any suggestions are truly appreciated.
Thanks always for your help.

Comment: You're missing a close-parenthesis the preceding line...

Comment: You're right. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the while loop. It's just typo mistake. Specifically the line -

```
  rmse_training.append(np.std(S_new[target] - mu_new)
```

is missing a closing parenthesis.
If you try

```
  rmse_training.append(np.std(S_new[target] - mu_new))
```

the error you're seeing will disappear.

It's very much worth noting that errors reported for a specific line are sometimes due to a syntax error earlier on, and this is something to look out for when debugging.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on it!

Comment: another question regarding the   rmse_training lists. I am appending the values as:   rmse_training.append(np.std(S_new[target] - mu_new)), but once the cycle finishes, I only get the last value. How can I get all of them within the while loop?

Comment: I am thinking about taking the rmse_training outside the while loop. Do you think that would work?